# PDF template not merging data properly with pdftk

Tags: python, pdf, pdftk, xfdf

I'm editing a PDF template with using pdftk

```
        command = ("pdftk " + '"' +
               template + '"' +
               " fill_form " + '"' +
               pathUser + user['mail'] + ".xfdf" + '"' +
               " output " + '"' +
               pathUser + user['mail'] + ".pdf" + '"' +
               " need_appearances")
        command = command.replace('/', '\\')
        os.system(command)
```

First I'm writing my data in a .xfdf file

```
    for key, value in user.items():
        print(key, value)
        fields.append(u"""<field name="%s"><value>%s</value></field>""" % (key, value))
    tpl = u"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <xfdf xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/" xml:space="preserve">
                <fields>
                    %s
                </fields>
            </xfdf>""" % "\n".join(fields)


    f = open(pathUser + user['mail'] + '.xfdf', 'wb')
    f.write(tpl.encode("utf-8"))
    f.close()
```

I fetch the template and as shown above, write the data from the xfdf to pdf but for some reason, only the `ime` gets written.

Templates get fetched using some basic conditional logic as shown below:

```
        for item in user['predavanja']:
            user[acthead + str(actn)] = item
            actn += 1
        for item in user['radionice']:
            user[acthead + str(actn)] = item
            actn += 1
        for item in user['izlet']:
            user[acthead + str(actn)] = item
            actn += 1
        print(actn)

        templates = {}
        templates['0'] = "Template/2019/certificate_2019.pdf"
        templates['5'] = "Template/2019/certificate_2019_5.pdf"
        templates['10'] = "Template/2019/certificate_2019_10.pdf"
        templates['15'] = "Template/2019/certificate_2019_15.pdf"
        templates['20'] = "Template/2019/certificate_2019_20.pdf"
        templates['25'] = "Template/2019/certificate_2019_25.pdf"
        templates['30'] = "Template/2019/certificate_2019_30.pdf"
        templates['35'] = "Template/2019/certificate_2019_35.pdf"
        templates['40'] = "Template/2019/certificate_2019_40.pdf"
        templates['45'] = "Template/2019/certificate_2019_45.pdf"
        templates['50'] = "Template/2019/certificate_2019_50.pdf"
```

I'm writing this data

```
    user['id'] = data['recommendations'][0]['role_in_team']['user']['id']
    user['ime'] = data['recommendations'][0]['role_in_team']['user']['first_name']
    user['prezime'] = data['recommendations'][0]['role_in_team']['user']['last_name']
    user['tim'] = data['recommendations'][0]['role_in_team']['team']['short_name']
    user['mail'] = data['recommendations'][0]['role_in_team']['user']['estudent_email']
    user['puno_ime'] = (data['recommendations'][0]['role_in_team']['user']['first_name'] + ' ' +
                        data['recommendations'][0]['role_in_team']['user']['last_name'])
                user['predavanja'] = predavanja
    user['radionice'] = radionice
    user['izlet'] = izlet
```

One note. `predavanja`, `radionice` and `izlet` are lists.
I've tried printing `tpl` which shows all the data being properly added to the scheme.

Comment: There are a few possible causes for this error, it may be that the xfdf is incorrectly generated, that the pdf is malformed, or that pdftk is buggy. Posting the actual xfdf and pdf would help finding where the problem lies.

Comment: I've opened the `xfdf` file by replacing the extension with `.xml` and the xfdf if definitely generated properly.  I'm guessing the issue then lies in the somewhere in the writing of the data in the pdf.

Here is the `.xfdf` converted into the `.xml` on this hastebin link
https://hastebin.com/cijafubapu.xml

Comment: The xfdf looks good to me, so I am leaning towards an issue with pdftk. If you report it at https://gitlab.com/pdftk-java/pdftk/issues and include the pdf I will be happy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was the naming of the variables since they didn't match the field names in the acroform PDF. So the solution was to rename the variables in the code to match the field names.